# Dual-booting with windows 8 (lots of partitions)

Tags: windows-8

I've just received my new Samsung 550p5c-AD1 which comes with windows 8 and a very weird partition table.

I'd like to keep Windows8 and dualboot with Ubuntu (12.04.2 64bits).

However I'm little confused with all of those Partitions. It is like this:

---

SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) - 1.0 TB ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M
    1.0 MB      FREE SPACE

#1 523.2 MB    ntfs        bASIC DATA P

#2 314.6 MB  B K   EFIboot     EFI system p

#3 134.2 MB            Microsoft re

#4 974.8 GB    ntfs        Basic data p

#5 23.3 GB     ntfs        Basic data p

#6 1.1 GB      fat32       Basic data p
    728.1 KB    FREE SPACE

---

How can I do? Should I resize Partition 4 (974GB)?

Woun't it mess up with Windows?

Comment: What in the world happened to that hard drive? Digital Tsunami? Electronic "hard quake". Can you add in what partition is the Windows system. the only one I can guess is #2 with the EFI boot.

Comment: See [installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Comment: Looks like it is in the partition 4 (974GB). For me it is really odd as well, I've never seen this pattern of partition table.

Answer (score 1):

Well .. thanks a lot for all of the help!!

Dual boot worked perfectly!! I hope this little script helps, this is what I've just done (and worked so far):

**Installation procedure** on this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) helped a lot!

Once Ubuntu was Up & Running I had little issue to boot Windows 8, which I fixed with  **boot-repair**, also in the same link above.

Boot repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
$ boot-repair
```

And last step was fixing the overheating (I'm still testing but it is good so far) with bumblebee, that is for Nvidia & Intel dual graphic cards.

Installation on this [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't mess with windows...

You can try a partition software and re-arange your partitions

(Windows 8 should have a small ~100MB system partition and another one for the OS ~50GB)

Comment: I hope so.

Is the partition 4 (974GB) to be resized, correct?

Comment: Also, is it possible to resize and create 2 Partitions? 

1 for /boot and 1 LVM (to install Linx)?

Comment: you can boot from a linux live CD/DVD and make the partitions as you want, you can combine two partitions. The only thing that will take time is when it moves data. If the partitions are almost full it will take a long time to process (2-5 hours, depending on how much data you have)

Comment: in the ubuntu's live cd terminal run "sudo apt-get install gparted" to install the partition manager

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help!! I'm gonna try that. But before that I'm trying to make a back-up of my entire disk, maybe with dd or maybe with g4u, just in case something goes wrong .. Any suggestion?  Or it's not needed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reduce partition 4, but it's safer to do it with Windows partitioning tools, not Linux tools.

Comment: Why do you say it's safer to use Windows for this? Also, *how* do you recommend doing it in Windows? You may want to give some brief advice about how to open Disk Management, assuming that's your recommendation.

Comment: i've resized partitions under windows and linux and i had no problems

Answer (score 0):

To resize/shrink a partition or volume in Windows, open the Disk Management tool.

This can be found through a simple search in the Start Menu search bar.

Once you open the tool, either select an existing volume/partition to shrink/resize, or select unallocated space to create a new volume/partition with.

If you choose to make a new partition, you will be asked for the desired size in MB, that of which cannot exceed the amount of unallocated space on your HDD(s), depending upon your hardware configuration (and whether or not you have any separate storage locations, like an actual secondary or 'jaz' drive).

If you choose to shrink an existing partition/volume, you will be asked for how many MB you wish for the requested partition to be reduced by. The system will perform a query when you choose to do the shrink, indicating the amount of space you can shrink from your chosen volume/partition. Your MB size cannot exceed the maximum delineated, for the sake of the existing file system (unless you wish to risk overwriting files and corrupting existing the file system). This will leave you with more unallocated space when complete, which you can use to create a new partition.

Once performed, you can then create a new partition and delineate it as a sort of virtual drive, which can be formatted, allowing for read-write access. This partition is the one you can mount a new OS to, if you so choose. Just be sure to choose the correct file system format type first.

As an added note, Linux and some UNIX OSs tend to need at least 6-10 GB of free space. Mac OS X needs 10-20 GB. A new Windows or DOS-based system may need at least 10-20 GB or more. ChromeOS and Android are a bit more forgiving, needing only 8-16 GB.

Good Luck!